# Hilbert space and Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, wavefunction, hilbert-space

Assume a system described by a Hamiltonian H, and assume that the eigenstates of H, $φ_i$(*r*) are integrable in absolute square. We say that these states belong to a Hilbert space (they can even form a base in that space).

But, is the opposite true? Let a system be described by a wave-function *S*(*r*, *t*), integrable in absolute square. Does that imply that the system behavior is also described by a Hamiltonian?

**Remark**: te evolution of a system does not always admit a Hamiltonian. E.g. if the evolution is non-unitary (or at least, if there is a Hamiltonian, it would take complex eigenvalues.) To be clear, **I don't know** if my system evolves unitarily or not. I just gave the example to show that the existence of a Hamiltonian is not guaranteed. Whatever I know of the function *S*(*r*, *t*) is that it belongs to a Hilbert space.

So the question is, absolute square-itegrability, ensures (as a sufficient condition) the existence of a Hamiltonian for the system?

**An example**: I expand *S*(*r*, *t*) in a quantum superposition of the eigenfunctions $φ_i$(r),

*S*(*r*, *t*) = $∑_i$ $C_i$(*t*) $φ_i$(*r*),    with    $C_i$(*t*) = $F_i$ (*t*) exp(-i$E_i$*t*/ħ).

Introducing this superposition in the Schrodinger equation with the Hamiltonian H, I obtain that iħ ∂*S*(*r*, *t*)/∂*t* is not equal with H*S*(*r*, *t*). But, could it be that another Hamiltonian H' may exist s.t. the Schrodinger eq. be satisfied?

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): Given an arbitrary orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space, it is possible to find infinitely many self-adjoint operators $H$ that are diagonal in that basis.

Comment: If the evolution is non-unitary, you are not describing the entire system, but an open subsystem! Unitarity is one of the few tenets that no proper quantum theory breaks when considering closed systems.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Yes, it seems simple. But something doesn't work. The discussed wave-function - let me call it S(r, t) - is tricky. Though abs. square-integrable, it is not an ordinary quantum-superposition of the base vectors ( $φ_i$(r) ) of the Hilbert space. What I have is S(r, t) = $∑_i$ $C_i$(t) $φ_i$(r). And the time-dependence of $C_i$(t) is not the ordinary dependence exp(-i$E_i$t/ħ), where $E_i$ are the energies of $φ_i$(r), but $C_i$(t) = exp[-i($E_i$ + Q)t/ħ], i.e. more complicated.

Comment: (continuation) By the way, it is a legitimate function in the Hilbert space. But introducing this superposition in the Schrodinger equation, the above time dependence makes trouble: what I obtain in the LHS (i.e. where I derivate by time) is not equal with what I get in the RHS. And I repeat, it's a legitimate function in the Hilbert space.

Comment: @Sofia Where do the $E_i$ come from? Some Hamiltonian I'd guess. The appearance of $Q$ merely shifts the whole spectrum by a constant. That has no physical consequence. The norm of the state $S$ is conserved during time-evolution, hence the dynamics is unitary.

Comment: @nephente : the evolution in time of an eigenstate $φ_i$(r) of the Hamiltonian, is of the form $φ_i$(r) exp(-i$E_i$  t/ħ), where $E_i$ is the energy of the quantum object in the state $φ_i$(r). But maybe you made a mistake and wanted to ask where from comes the quantity Q in the exponents of $C_i$(t). I obtain this Q when developing S(r, t) in a superposition of the functions $φ_i$(r). I would be VERY happy to known what is the physical interpretation of Q, but at this stage I am not able to say. So, what I know is that the function S(r, t) is abs. square integrable, and that's it.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, the answer is obviously ***no***. Your question in mathematical terms: there exists an "evolution" map $E:\mathbb{R}\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (that to each time associates a square-integrable function). Can I then conclude there exist a strongly continuous group of linear unitary operators $U:\mathbb{R}\times L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $E(t)=U(t)\psi$ for some $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$? Suppose that $E$ is not ***continuous***. Then $E$ cannot be genrated by any $U(t)$, since the latter are strongly continuous by hypothesis.

Comment: Even relaxing the condition on $U$ to be a $C^0$-semigroup (that may allow, roughly speaking, non self-adjoint generators), again you could not realize any non-continuous $E$. Finally, I am quite confident that requiring that $E$ is a continuous or even differentiable map would again not be enough to guarantee that in general it is realized by a family of linear operators acting on $L^2$ (let alone a unitary group or $C^0$-semigroup).

Comment: @yuggib, I regret but I learnt group theory TOO many years ago. And I have no time to refresh my knowledge now, and neither in the near future. Can you, for the moment, formulate your comment, without groups? I would be very glad. With thanks in advance.

Comment: What I mean is that your question translates to asking whether the existence of an "evolution" map implies also this map is continuous (and furthermore generated by the action of a linear operator, maybe self-adjoint or maybe not). You see by very elementary examples the answer is no, because there exist functions that are not continuous. To be explicit: the map $$E(t)=\left\{\begin{aligned}0\text{ if $t\leq 0$}\\e^{-t x^2}\text{$if t> 0$}\end{aligned}\right .$$ is not continuous and therefore there exist no linear operator $H$ such that $E(t)=e^{-itH}\psi$ for some $\psi\in L^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with the notion of *unitary time evolution* also possesses the notion of *Hamiltonian*.

If $\mathcal{U}(t) : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is the time evolution operator for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then it forms a one-parameter Lie subgroup of the Lie group of unitary operators, which is generated by some distinct element $H$ in the Lie algebra of linear operators. This generator is the Hamiltonian, and as the generator of a unitary operator, it is necessarily self-adjoint by [Stone's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups), so you get a Hamiltonian whose eigenvectors span the space.

Since non-unitary time-evolution comes into play if you are only considering a *subspace* of the full space of states (e.g. when you don't track all decay products for decaying systems), one can always get a unitary evolution by embedding the subsystem into "the whole system", find the Hamiltonian there, and then project it back onto the subsystem to get the Hamiltonian for the subsystem. But now, since time evolution was non-unitary here, it cannot be that this Hamiltonian is self-adjoint (since the exponential of self-adjoint operators is unitary), therefore we are forced to conclude that the eigenvectors of a Hamiltonian cannot span a subspace on which time evolution is non-unitary.

So, you cannot get a Hamiltonian both spanning the space *and* producing non-unitary time evolution, one of these must necessarily fail.

Comment: [Stone's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups) states that unitary evolution groups are generated by _self-adjoint_ operators, not just hermitian ones, so  there's no need to do any extension. Actually different extensions of hermitian operators yield different unitary evolution groups.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I saw that you answered and I read your comment, but I have to leave the computer now. I return much later. Let me say just in short. It is a disputed question whether the decay is unitary or not. So, I am not sure on this. In my question I only gave an example that existence of a Hamiltonian is not guaranteed. THAT'S ALL !!!. I don't know anything else about my system than the fact that its wave-function is abs. square-integrable. So, here comes my question. Abs. square integrability ensures the existence of a Hamiltonian? But, as I say, I'll return later.

Comment: @Sofia: I answer that, regardless of where the non-unitary evolution comes from: If time-evolution is non-unitary, you do not get a Hamitonian that simultaneously generates the time evolution **and** whose eigenvectors span the space on which the non-unitary evolution takes place.

Comment: @Mateus: I am ignorant about the difference between a self-adjoint operator and a Hermitian one. I saw other people too claiming that there is a difference. What is this difference? But please, if possible, give me a simple explanation. What features has one, and doesn't have the other? What I learnt is that BOTH have the property of REAL eigenvalues. I hope that this is not wrong.

Comment: @Sofia: It is wrong, Hermitian not-self-adjoint operators can have complex eigenvalues. The difference exists only on infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, where the domains of definitions of linear operators need not necessarily be the whole space. An operator $A$ is Hermitian if it is the same as $A^\dagger$ on its domain of definition. It is self-adjoint if the domains of definition of $A$ and $A^\dagger$ coincide *and* they are the same on it. A nice overview of the issues with this difference is [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907069).

Comment: @ACuriousMind: the difference is indeed only a matter of domains, but Hermitian operators **cannot** have complex eigenvalues, since that if $A\psi=a\psi$ for some $a\in\Bbb{C}$ and a normalized $\psi$, we have that: $$a=\langle\psi,a\psi\rangle=\langle\psi,A\psi\rangle=\langle A^*\psi,\psi\rangle=\langle A\psi,\psi\rangle=\langle a\psi,\psi\rangle=a^*$$ i.e., $a\in\Bbb{R}$. What can happen, and indeed does when the hermitian operator is not self-adjoint is that it has complex values in the _spectrum_, but not complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @MateusSampaio: You're right. I forgot that there's a difference between spectrum and eigenvalue in the infinite-dimensional case, too.

Comment: @ACuriousMind and MateusSampaio: Both of you are very kind, but I have to do with Hamiltonians that admit COMPLEX eigenvalues. Some acquaintance told me that these complex values are acceptable **outside** the Hilbert space. But now, it's terribly late in my country, I hope to communicate with you tomorrow.

Comment: @Sofia: It's better if you ping MateusSampaio with your @, since I'm notified automatically as the owner of this post when a comment appears. I know of Feshbach's theory, though not in great detail. It seems to be that it is, because of the interaction with the environment, not a closed system, so you may get "Hamiltonians" that aren't self-adjoint.

Comment: No, I understand that I disturb you too much. It's unfair from my part.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't see why that should be the case. The notion of a Hilbertspace underlying a quantum-mechanical system is quite independant of the postulate that time evolution is generated by a Hamiltonian.

The notion of a vectorspace enters QM, because fundamentaly QM should be a linear theory and thus allow for arbitrary superpositions. The more wonderous idea is, that it is a space over the complex numbers.

The fact that a proper wavefunction should be $L^2$ reflects the interpretation as a probability-/ or charge-density.

Any (sensible) Hilbertspace admits a countable orthonormal basis. Pick a real number for each of those basis states and define

$$ (H)_{mn} = \langle \psi_m,H\psi_n\rangle \equiv \epsilon_n$$

as matrix elements of an operator $H$. What kind of dynamics this "Hamiltonian" describes, depends on the choice of eigenvalues, e.g energies. You should also make sure, that the spectrum is not too pathological, e.g it should be bounded from below to be interpretable as a sensible physical spectrum.

Non-unitary time-evolutions come about in *open* quantum systems, where you forget about the environment which couples to the system of interest, but which is nevertheless there. Probability can "leak" into the environment, hence a non-unitary evolution. An example is e.g the Lindblatt-Master-Equation describing the Markovian limit of a system-environment coupling.

Comment: So really, you are arguing that closed systems with a sensible probability density function should by definition be described by a Hamiltonian, whereas in an open system it is not the case. Am I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: @PhotonicBoom I mean, you can't do with a Hilbertspace alone to describe a physical system. Some dynamical input is needed. One of the postulates of QM is that state evolution is generated by a Hamiltonian operator. The implicit assumption is, the system is closed. No coupling to an environment. Even with an "environment" the total system can still be considered closed and is thus governed by unitary time-evolution. It is only when one passes to an effective description of the subsystem by tracing out the environment, that non-unitary dynamics arise.